# How to delete a prepared statement in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, prepared-statement, libpg

I already create & use prepared statements by utilizing the libpq (of PostgreSQL). I am wondering if there is a way to delete a prepared statement without disconnecting the database? Or the best way to achieve this is to reconnect & re-prepare?

I am using the libpq of PostgreSQL version 8.4. I searched the 9.2 documentation but could not find anything related to this...

Comment: You mean something like `DEALLOCATE`? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-deallocate.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: So there is no function in libpq but this ? I was expecting to delete the statement the way I prepared it. Anyway, Thanks a lot...

Comment: I have no idea. I don't use libpg, only JDBC.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html), `DEALLOCATE` is the only way to delete a prepared statement, emphasis added:

> Prepared statements for use with PQexecPrepared can also be created by
>   executing SQL PREPARE statements. Also, although **there is no libpq
>   function for deleting a prepared statement**, the SQL DEALLOCATE
>   statement can be used for that purpose.

Presumably they did not bother to expose a C function for this because this would be as simple as:

```
  char query[NAMEDATALEN+12];
  snprintf(query, sizeof(query), "DEALLOCATE %s", stmtName);
  return PQexec(conn, query);
```

Comment: @Daniel I have a prepared statement and it works fine most of the time. However at some point that statement gets deleted automatically and I start getting "Prepared statement doesn't extists." errors, please help me How I can check whether prepared statement is good or not. Please help!!!

Comment: @Amit: maybe you get reconnected. Prepared statements are freed upon disconnect. Create a new question with details on your context for more

Answer (score 3):

As @Amit mentioned, sometimes Postgress throws "Prepared statement doesn't exists."

Unfortunately, there is no `DEALLOCATE IF EXISTS`, but a simple workaround is:
`DEALLOCATE ALL;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete one prepared statement in the current session:

```sql
DEALLOCATE PREPARE <name>;
```

And, you can delete all the prepared statements in the current session:

```sql
DEALLOCATE PREPARE ALL;
```

*Memos:

- You can omit `PREPARE` which is optional.
- Prepared statements are deleted after logout.
- [The doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-deallocate.html) explains `DEALLOCATE` statement in detail.